# Format of train/test for random forest classifier with categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Updated: How do I set up my train/test df for scikit randomforestclassifier for multiple categories? How do I predict?

My training dataset has a categorical Outcome column with 4 classes and I want to predict which of those four is most likely for my test data. Looking at other questions, I tried use pandas get_dummies to encode four new columns into the original df in place of the original Outcome column but wasn't sure how to indicate to the classifier that those four columns were the categories, so I used `y = df_raw['Outcomes'].values` .

I then split the training set 80/20 and called fit() with these x_train, x_valid and y_train, y_valid:

```
def split_vals(a,n): return a[:n].copy(), a[n:].copy() 
n_valid = 10000 
n_trn = len(df_raw_dumtrain)-n_valid
raw_train, raw_valid = split_vals(df_raw_dumtrain, n_trn)
X_train, X_valid = split_vals(df_raw_dumtrain, n_trn)
y_train, y_valid = split_vals(df_raw_dumtrain, n_trn)

random_forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
random_forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
Y_prediction = random_forest.predict(X_train)
```

I tried running fit() as:

```
test_pred = random_forest.predict(df_test)
```

But I get an error:

> ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input.
>   Model n_features is 27 and input n_features is 28

How should I be configuring my test set?

Comment: When you say you "dummy encoded" your targets, what does that mean? One-hot encoding? In which case, did you do it manually, use pandas get_dummies, or use the [sklearn labelencoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)?

Comment: One-hot encoding via pandas get_dummies.

    df_raw_dum = pd.get_dummies(df_raw['Outcome'])
    df_raw_dumtrain = pd.concat([df_raw, df_raw_dum], axis=1)
    df_raw_dumtrain.drop('Outcome', axis=1, inplace=True)

Comment: And what is the actual error message? (Note: Please edit this and the previous comment into the question itself, as code formatting doesn't come out great in comments)

Comment: The code in your example uses RandomForestRegressor instead of RandomForestClassifier

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the target variable from the test data and then give the remaining column of the dataframe as the input for the prediction function. You would able to solve the number of features mismatch.

Try this!

```
random_forest.predict(df_test.drop('Outcomes',axis=1))
```

Note : you don't have to create dummy variables of the target variables for using the random forest or any decision tree based models.